# VBA to Excel how do i get data name and phone numbers instead of hyperlinks?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

```
Sub GetAllLinks()

    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    url_name = "http://www.trovanumeri.com/?azione=cerca&cerca=portoscuso"
    If url_name = "" Then Exit Sub
    IE.navigate url_name
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
    '<a href="http://google.com">Click Here
    Set AllHyperLinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
    Foglio1.ListBox1.Clear
    'this is the code
    For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
        Foglio1.ListBox1.AddItem hyper_link
    Next
    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Using just `hyper_link` in `foglio1.ListBox1.AddItem hyper_link` will give you the link itself. If you want to know what the display name is, use `foglio1.ListBox1.AddItem hyper_link.InnerText`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below example, showing how to retrieve the data from via IE automation and DOM processing:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

    Dim oIE As Object
    Dim lCurRow As Long
    Dim lResultIndex As Long
    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim oTable0 As Object
    Dim oTable1 As Object
    Dim oTable2 As Object
    Dim oTable3 As Object
    Dim sTbl3Text As String
    Dim cAncorNodes As Object
    Dim oAncorNode As Variant
    Dim sRowText As String
    Dim oRowNode As Object
    Dim aData() As Variant

    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With oIE
        .Visible = True
        Sheets(1).Cells.Delete
        lCurRow = 1 ' Worksheet rows counter
        lResultIndex = 0 ' Search result index counter
        Do
            ' Navigate to the page
            sUrl = "http://www.trovanumeri.com/?azione=cerca&cerca=cagliari&da=" & lResultIndex
            .Navigate sUrl
            ' Wait IE
            Do While .ReadyState < 3 Or .Busy
                DoEvents
            Loop
            ' Wait Document
            Do Until .Document.ReadyState = "complete"
                DoEvents
            Loop
            ' Retrieve target tables
            Set oTable0 = .Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
            Set oTable1 = oTable0.getElementsByTagName("table")(1)
            Set oTable2 = oTable1.getElementsByTagName("table")(3)
            ' Get and process ancor nodes
            Set cAncorNodes = oTable2.getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each oAncorNode In cAncorNodes
                With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    ' Add .href to result
                    .Add .Count, oAncorNode.href
                    ' Get ancor's parent row
                    Set oRowNode = oAncorNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode
                    Do
                        ' Add nonemtpy row to result
                        sRowText = Trim(Replace(oRowNode.innerText, vbCrLf, ""))
                        If sRowText <> "" Then .Add .Count, sRowText
                        ' If last row then exit
                        If IsNull(oRowNode.nextElementSibling) Then Exit Do
                        ' Proceed with next row
                        Set oRowNode = oRowNode.nextElementSibling
                        ' If net row contains oAncorNode then exit
                        If oRowNode.getElementsByTagName("a").Length > 0 Then Exit Do
                        DoEvents
                    Loop
                    ' Get results as array
                    aData = .Items
                End With
                ' Output array to worksheet row
                With Sheets(1).Cells(lCurRow, 1)
                    .Resize(1, UBound(aData) + 1) = aData
                    .Select
                End With
                lCurRow = lCurRow + 1
                DoEvents
            Next
            ' Get table containing 'Next' button
            Set oTable3 = oTable0.getElementsByTagName("table")(7)
            sTbl3Text = oTable3.innerText
            ' If no 'Next' button then exit
            If InStr(sTbl3Text, "Avanti >>") = 0 Then Exit Do
            lResultIndex = lResultIndex + 10
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```